# Why divs with backgrounds aren't displayed as one below other?

Tags: html, css

I'm stucked. I've tried different solutions but it doesn;t work for me - I do something wrong.

I want to get 2 divs (there is more, but it should be enough to solve the problem): header and menu. Both of them have got background-images. I want to set 'menu' directly below 'header' using responsive approach.

```
<div id="header_main"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

i CSS:

```
#header_main{
background-image: url(../images/headerPapyrus.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat:
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
}
#menu{
background-image: url(../images/bgMenu.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat:
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
}
```

I want to get divwith dimensions in line with its background images widht and height, but responsive. Please give me any adice how I can do it properly.

Comment: Can you share with code snippets ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now two images appear on top of each other, that's why you would only be able to see one of them.

Try to wrap them in a seperate div and give `display:flex` to that div. This way you could achieve what you want I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Change your position on the header to `position: relative;` and set both of them to `display: flex;`

Like this:

```css
#header_main{
background-image: url(../images/headerPapyrus.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat:
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
display: flex;
}
#menu{
background-image: url(../images/bgMenu.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat:
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_main">header</div>
<div id="menu">menu</div>
```

Comment: wouldnt you remove the position: absolute on the #menu?

Answer (score 0):

These are specific methods for creating responsive background:

```
  /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;

  /* Background image doesn't tile */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
  background-size: cover;
```

And why do you give the elements position absolute and take them out of the normal flow? You can use maybe :

```
#header_main{
   position: relative;
};   

#menu{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
};
```